# How to install Yubikey personalization tool on Ubuntu

Tags: ppa, yubikey

How to install binary version of https://www.yubico.com/support/downloads for Ubuntu. I'm using 14.04 LTS.

[edit]

Also how to fix "An unexpected error has occurred" in Google Account

Answer (score 5):

This is [the official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~yubico/+archive/ubuntu/stable), open a terminal and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yubico/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install yubikey-personalization yubikey-personalization-gui
```

To enable use without sudo (e.g. Google Chrome), update `udev` rules:

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yubico/libu2f-host/master/70-u2f.rules
sudo service udev restart
```

Comment: I've also changed the mode, but not sure if it was necessary: `ykpersonalize -m6`

Comment: `udevadm control --reload-rules` is slightly better than restarting udev.